# What do I use for the UserId field in the Data Exporter?

Tags: discussion, comments, data-explorer

I am checking all comments made by me using [this Data Exporter query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/10698/my-comments#messages). However, when I type in `jugadu` as the UserId nothing comes up.

What should I type in the UserId field? Where I can get this UserId? Can anyone please help me to see my all comments?

Comment: User id is numeric you can see on your profile url [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246335/jugadu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/2875348/jugadu
                               ^^^^^^^
```

Your userid is 2875348

---

**EDIT**

> Can you show me one of them? –  Jugadu 5 mins ago

Sure :

[image]

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

[image]

Comment: Yaa my UserId is 2875348 Thanks for that. But when I click on link provided in post link column I get runtime error page. Why??

Comment: Can you show me one of them?

Comment: Thank you so much. I think there is some problem with my browser I am getting `:)text` into post link column.

Comment: Now its works fine, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Go to your profile, you'll see something like that in your browser:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/1735406/maroun-maroun
                               ↑
```

The number is your ID. In your case:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your `userId` as in the number that is there before your name in your profile url: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2875348/jugadu. The userId should be `2875348`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the number of your user id:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246335/jugadu

So try 246335

Comment: That is his ID for MSO, not SO.

Comment: Well, he will get the concept now I think. That's the most important.

Comment: Perhaps, but not all users are aware that your ID is not unique across the different stack exchange sites. Cheers.

Comment: If he reads these comments, I think he will! +1